# How to filter a Notion database for a specific given date

Tags: notion

I'm trying to connect multiple parts of my Notion so that it's easier to use day to day. For that reason, I made a calendar view in order to easily see the different things I put into notion every day. I have a calculations page which is a table view and each entry is a calculation I did that day. I wanted to have a page in my main calendar where I could see that table but only the calculations that were started that day. I tried going into each day and making a table relating to the calculations database and filtering to only the calculations that have the same date but the filter doesn't give me the option to select a specific day, it will only let it relate to the present, past or future date. Anyone know how to get around that?

Comment: can I ask if you ever solve this?